# Call a function with href

Tags: plugins, functions, actions

Is there any way to call a function inside plugin with `<a href='plugin-function'>` tag? I need this to show user details which will not be bound to any action hook.

Answer (score 1):

You can echo the return value of a function:

```
<a href='<?php echo plugin_function(); ?>'>
```

But without seeing the actual function, there is no way to give a more specific answer.